# Steps to normalise this posterior (if possible) with a t -data distribution likelihood

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am trying to normalised an unnormalised posterior density $p_{unnormalised}(\theta | x)$ but unsure the best way to proceed without being caught in an algebraic mess.

The posterior density is given by $p(\theta, \sigma^{2} | x) = \frac{L(\theta, \sigma^{2}| x)\pi(\theta)}{Z}$ and prior $\pi(\theta) = 1$

The data generating model $p(x | \theta, \sigma^{2})$, with degrees of freedom $v = 2$ and $\sigma_{2} = 40^{2}$ is given as a t -distribution like

$p(x | \theta) = t_{v}(x | \theta, 40^{2}) = t_{v}(x | \theta) \propto (1 + \frac{1}{v}(\frac{x- \theta}{\sigma})^{2} ) ^{-(v + 1) / 2}$

But taking the log of $p(x | \theta, 40^{2})$ and letting $v = 2$, the log - likelihood $l(\theta | x) = log L(\theta | x)$ gives $l(\theta |x) = \frac{-3}{2}ln[\frac{2 + (x - \theta)^{2}}{40^{2}}]$

The un - normalised posterior density is

$p_{unnormalised}(\theta | x) \propto l(\theta | x) = \frac{-3}{2}ln[\frac{2 + (x - \theta)^{2}}{40^{2}}]$

To normalise the unnormalised posterior $p_{unnormalised}(\theta | x)$, note that the evidence
$Z = \int_{\theta} p(\theta, x).d\theta$. But $p_{unnormalised}(\theta , x) = p_{unnormalised}(x | \theta) \pi(\theta)$ so that $Z = \int_{\theta} p_{unnormalised}(x | \theta) \pi(\theta).d\theta$.

Does this leaves me to integrate $p_{unnoramlised}(x | \theta) \pi(\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ where $p_{unnoramlised} = (1 + \frac{1}{v}(\frac{x- \theta}{\sigma})^{2} ) ^{-(v + 1) / 2}$? Is this the best method?